# How to write multiple response BaseModel in FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I want to display multiple response model, so I have defined responses in a file and importing it to main file as below

```
@app.post("/mask", responses=Example_Mask)
```

in my `response.py` I have defined `Example_Mask` as

```
class Example_Mask(BaseModel):

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "200": {"model": Example_200_Mask},
                "422": {"model": Example_422_Mask},
                "500": {"model": Example_500},
                "504": {"model": Example_504}
            }
        }
```

I have defined all `Example` models in the same way, but I am getting

> TypeError: 'ModelMetaclass' object is not a mapping

error. Can you pls tel me where is this wrong?

Comment: You want to show multiple responses within the same request?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Have a different example, or a different response pattern?

Comment: @daniboy000 , yes mutiple response for /mask api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently pass to responses is not something that can be mapped. You are currently passing it an Object (`class Example_Mask (BaseModel)`).

To work response, needs values that it can map to, namely, your `schema_extra` from `Config` if you remove the `example` key

So to work you can do this:

```py
class Example_Mask(BaseModel):

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
                "200": {"model": Example_200_Mask},
                "422": {"model": Example_422_Mask},
                "500": {"model": Example_500},
                "504": {"model": Example_504}
        }

@app.post("/mask", responses=Example_Mask.Config.schema_extra)
```

Or you can just pass a dictionary, out of class:

```py
responses = {
   "200": {"model": Example_200_Mask},
   "422": {"model": Example_422_Mask},
   "500": {"model": Example_500},
   "504": {"model": Example_504}
}

@app.post("/mask", responses=responses)
```

I'm not a FastAPI expert, so I can't assure this is the most consistent way, but anyway it works.